# Regex to trim down a Windows File Path

Tags: regex

I have a bit of a challenge for my limited regex knowledge.
I must setup a windows video server so that this path :

\192.168.1.6\Medias\AMA\20210408_PROJECT_NAME\CAM\PRIVATE\M4ROOT\CLIP

I must use regex in a given field in order to output this :

20210408_PROJECT_NAME

Then I need to write a second expression that outputs this :

CAM

The chunks I want to clear are set in stone, however the project name and cam are variable in length and format.

I wrote this expression :

```
^(?!\\\\192.168.1.6\\Medias\\AMA\\|PRIVATE\\|M4ROOT\\|CLIP).*
```

In order to clear out what I don't need.
And for some reason it doesn't work, could you lead me in the right direction ?

Comment: What is "given field"? Where are you using the regex? Is it replacing? Extracting? What is the regex flavor?

Comment: I'm using a video server, the video server can use metadata to generate pathing. In this specific case I can draw the full path of the source. I then need to extract the information I need from this path in order to mimic the *relevant* tree structure for my transcoded destination. I'm not sure about the regex flavor, I assume Python, I asked support

Comment: What about `^(\\192.168.1.6\\Medias\\AMA\\([0-9A-Z_\\]+)\\PRIVATE\\M4ROOT\\CLIP)$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return project name

```
AMA\\(.+)\\.+\\PRIVATE
```

See it working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wZ5e2q/1).

This will return... the other thing (CAM) :)

```
AMA\\.+\\(.+)\\PRIVATE
```

See it working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OFCctD/1).

Comment: As simple as that ! 8o Thank you !

Comment: If this or any other answer was helpful, upvote it. When you find the answer that solves your issue, please mark it as accepted so that others don't waste time answering an answered question.

Comment: I'm afraid I got carried away. It does indeed work but I need to come up with different results in order to achieve my goal. First I need a regex that will output 20210408_PROJECT_NAME then I need another one that will output CAM (no slash)

Comment: If that's the case, you need to update your question stating exactly what you are expecting to receive. You need to be really careful in the future when asking questions like this and figure out what you want the final output to be. People will spend time on this question and get you the answer that you want and then you've really changed the question to a new one which is not supposed to happen. In this case I think they're close so I would just edit the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer to fit your new request.

Comment: I got feedback from the support team stating that \ could not be processed in the metadata field, sorry about that.

Comment: @Matayo Ah... that makes sense then. Stuff happens. Try the updated answer, it should do what you are asking.

Comment: Wow Jeff, I'm so impressed by your skills ! However I need one expression that outputs the first field, then another expression that outputs the second field, can't handle multiple answers. I'll try and play with question marks :)

Comment: Ok, got it... AMA\\(?:.+)\\(.+)\\PRIVATE and AMA\\(.+)\\(?:.+)\\PRIVATE, TY Jef, May I suggest you change your answer so I mark it as solved ?THANK YOU !!!! <3

Comment: I edited my answer. I did it a little differently than you did. Both have working links to regex101.com. If you haven't already, look carefully at the right side of the page on that site. I have found it very useful in understanding and learning regex, explaining what each part does, and the quick reference list is really helpful also.

Comment: You are awesome !